# JWPlayer IE issues, screen going blank after being hidden and shown

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, video, cross-browser, jwplayer

I'm using jwplayer in html tabs in IE with jQuery showing and hiding them (via style:hidden;)

When I hide a tab in IE and then show it again the plays video area goes blank (you can still hear sound and play/pause the video).

Does anyone know why this is happening or have a way to fix it.

Cheers.

Here's the jQ doing the hiding / showing:

```
function showpanel(panel){
  jQuery('#announcements .panel').each(function(index) {
    if(panel == index) {
      jQuery(this).css('visibility','visible');
    } else {
      jQuery(this).css('visibility','hidden');
    }
  });
  jQuery('#announcements .nav ul li.item').each(function(index) {
    if(panel == index) {
      jQuery(this).addClass("active");
    } else {
      jQuery(this).removeClass("active");
    }
  });  
}
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
showpanel(0);
  jQuery('#announcements .nav ul li.item').each(function(index) {
      jQuery(this).mouseover(function(){
                    if(jQuery(this).hasClass("active")){                           
             //console.log('if'); 
                    } else {  
                        //console.log('else');
                        document.getElementById('jw_player').sendEvent('PLAY', 'false');
                        showpanel(index);
                    }
                });
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem on Chrome 15 and JWPlayer 5.8.

Answer (score 1):

I used...

```
if(panel == index) {
      jQuery(this).css('z-index','2');
    } else {
      jQuery(this).css('z-index','1');
    }
```

Instead of the visibility and it worked great.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to fix this solution is to remove the player when another tab is clicked. Then load the player back in when that tab is clicked/re-clicked. You can remove the player by using jwplayer("container").remove(); -- assuming your div with the player in it is an id named container. To add it back in just place the same jwplayer("container").setup({...}); in that function.